# Spring context destroyed during waitForExecutionToCompleteOnShutdown

Tags: spring, tomcat7, quartz-scheduler, applicationcontext

I have a Spring application with many scheduled Quartz jobs in it. When Tomcat's `shutdown.sh` file is executed, Tomcat stops. However, I want all my jobs to complete their execution, then I want application server to stop.

That works fine: all executing jobs finish their jobs before the server shuts down. However, Spring context is destroyed when I execute `shutdown.sh`. So any kind of DB operations etc. processes can not be done because I get a `NoClassDefFoundError`.

How can I handle this situation? I want Spring context to be destroyed after my Quartz jobs finish their execution.

Comment: I'm in a similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27846280/tomcat-servlets-destroy-not-completing-after-service-tomcat7-stop -- without Spring however