# Tomcat Servlet's destroy() not completing after 'service tomcat7 stop'

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, servlets

I have a Servlet app which spawns worker threads in the `init()` method. These workers continually do transactional jobs i.e. it's important that each job, if started, is completed or else not started.

I hoped that I could use the `destroy()` method to stop these worker Threads in a graceful way, i.e. making sure they were finished with whatever last/current job before ending the `destroy()` method and terminating the Servlet.

The `destroy()` is triggered when a Chef scripts executes `service tomcat7 stop`

But from my logs/tests, the `destroy()` method on my Servlet does not block/complete. It is triggered, but then after a few moments, tomcat shuts down and I don't receive confirmation that the Threads stopped in a graceful way.

```
public void destroy() {
  log.info("Signaling worker to stop current job/not begin another.");
  this.worker.stop();
  while(this.worker.isProcessingJob()) {
    Thread.sleep(3 * 1000);
  }
  log.info("Worker successfully stopped");
  log.info("destroy() complete");
  super.destroy();
}
```

In many cases I don't see the last two logs, i.e. Tomcat goes down when my code is in `while-loop` waiting for `this.worker` to complete it's current job.

Is this expected behavior? Is there some way to tell tomcat to stop, but also allow my Servlet's `destroy()` method to block/complete?

Comment: If You are using Tomcat within Eclipse, make sure that the server time-out is configured with proper values

Comment: What logging framework are you using? Are you sure your logging framework is not buffering the log statements, and is cleanly shutdown?

Comment: Actually, Servlet spec 3.1 is rather thin on this (shutdown behavior of container). Your 2 best bets: A -- contact Tomcat devs (e.g., via mailing lists) and B -- (which is proactive and improves overall robustness) make your transactions log-based, so, in case of a failure, you'll get consistent state subsequently.

Comment: @VictorSorokin this is using Log4j. I don't think buffering has ever been an issue before in my app. I can confirm that `service tomcat7 stop` is not allowing `destroy()` to finish (on Ubuntu 14.04 in production env)

Comment: @mmcrae Your answer a bit misdirected :)

Comment: @VictorSorokin lol woops. As to what you *actually* said, would you mind putting that as an answer and going into more detail on option 'B'? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: @mmcrae see http://engineering.linkedin.com/distributed-systems/log-what-every-software-engineer-should-know-about-real-time-datas-unifying

Comment: @VictorSorokin I appreciate the all-encompassing article, but it seems a little theoretical or over-the-top. Is this suggesting I use a database to store state for the different threads? And then have each Thread check the state of other threads in the database while working? I just have more questions after reading some of this, which is why I would really appreciate if you wrote an answer more on practically how I can utilize this.

Comment: I'm a bit sorry, this is overly broad question for SO, that's why I gave answer in comment, not a proper answer. The minimum you can take away from the article is that once you have log (journal) of changes done by your workers, you can re-create state of your app after a failure. It's not necessarily must be a database, for simple tasks append-only file can suffice.

Comment: Can you confirm that Tomcat itself has actually stopped (i.e. logs something like "Tomcat connector stopped") and is not killed? If not, I might have an idea of the cause (stop-timeout in Chef/upstart script).

Comment: yes I can confirm tomcat stops by viewing the Catalina.out logs. I'm starting to think it's not an issue with Chef or anything -- that this is expected behavior with Tomcat or some Tomcat implementations.

Comment: Found [this old post](http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/shutdown-sh-and-graceful-shutdown-td2158010.html) which mentions a [Context unloadDelay](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html) (default 2 seconds). Considering the [StandardWrapper](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc7.0.x/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/core/StandardWrapper.java)'s `unload()` method, that might do the trick. Also, making the worker threads non-daemon might prevent the JVM from stopping?

Comment: wow that seems like a real gem. That might do the trick. Thank you!

Comment: Another thing: I think Tomcat will wait for a `contextDestroyed` method to finish (I have had that method blocking for up to 30 seconds without trouble). So maybe you can move the workers start/stop code to a `ServletContextListener`.